# poor result after installation

Tags: 11.10

I just have downloaded ubuntu 11.10 on my old 5.10 version, and successfuly burned in on to DVD, and installed 11.10 instead, after successful installation I was forced to restart pc, my DVD had been ejected. after restart pink screen appeared, was blank all the time, so I decided to restart again, this time I was able to select between 4 possibilities

1. ubuntu with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic
2. ubuntu with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (recover mode)
3. memory test
4. memory test ...

I selected first and pressed enter to boot, but still no results, black screen appears after few seconds, saying "busybox (...) type help for commands" after next seconds its flooded by logs saying something about killing or terminating signals, and nothing. I have no idea what can I do, I will be grateful for some tips, I'm real beginner with Linux. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reinstall Grub from live media (in response to your comment on CGriffitt's answer):

First, boot from your Ubuntu LiveCD, and choose "Try Ubuntu"; let it continue until you get the default Live desktop. From the Dash, open a terminal and enter the command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This is to find out the partition to which you have installed Ubuntu. It'll be sdXY, where X is the drive: it'll be a letter such as a or b; and Y is the number that has been given to the partition on that drive: it'll be a number. Find your Ubuntu partition there, if you can. You need to know X and Y. (If you can't tell which is the right partition, you can open GParted from the Dash to get a graphical view of your partitions, and maybe figure it out from there.)

Once you know that, then enter the command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

where X and Y are the partition that you found in the previous step. For example, if your Ubuntu partition is sda1, you'll enter "sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt". This is to mount the partition so that you can work with files on it.

Now you need to reinstall grub to that partition. If you're running Ubuntu 11.04 or later, enter this command:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX
```

where X is the partition (a, b, c, etc.) that you obtained above: note that it does not take a number this time.

If your version of Ubuntu is older than 11.04, then enter this command instead:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
```

This will reinstall the Ubuntu grub you had been using before. When you reboot, you'll have your old grub. Once in to your Ubuntu, open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer (this has not happened to me, but I had a somewhat similar issue and this helped.): Reinstall GRUB from the live media (for me it was a USB, but you may have chosen a CD)

Comment: could you please,tell me how to do that? I have already reinstaled whole Linux again and the same, thanks for reply

Comment: follow instructions here very carefully: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099